# How to filter a dataframe based on multiple conditions with another dataframe

Tags: r, filter

I have a call data - call it `total_call` which stores all the calls that was made to and from our telephone numbers. This data-frame contains the call_id, the number of the caller and the number of the receiver, the retrieved-datetime.

The column names are listed respectively like this:

```
# total_call data
call_id | from_number | to_number | retrieved_date
1         1              2          2020-01-12 12:03:34
2         2              1          2020-01-12 12:06:34
3         1              3          2020-01-15 13:02:40
4         2              1          2020-01-15 13:05:40
```

The second data-frame i have is the `missed_call` data, which was filtered from the first one. It has the same column names as the first one but on the `to_number` field, it is just our telephone numbers.  I have a way to know which call is from our lines to the customers and vice versa.

```
# missed_call data
call_id | from_number | to_number | retrieved_date
1         1              2          2020-01-12 12:03:34
3         1              3          2020-01-15 13:02:40
```

Now I need to know if the missed call had been called back or not. My solution is matching the `from_number` of the `missed_call` data with the `to_number` of the `total_call` data and limiting  the difference between these two `retrieved_date` to 2 hours maximum. I tried to merge these data-frames then used *ifelse* but there were a lot of duplicate observations of the phone numbers which made the merging progress wrong.

```
# After merging, i have this (f_num: from_number; t_num: to_number)
f_num|call_id.x|t_num.x|retrieved_date.x   |call_id.y|f_num.y|retrieved_date.y
1     1         2       2020-01-12 12:03:34 2         2       2020-01-12 12:06:34
1     1         2       2020-01-12 12:03:34 4         2       2020-01-15 13:05:40  
1     3         3       2020-01-15 13:02:40 2         2       2020-01-12 12:06:34
1     3         3       2020-01-15 13:02:40 4         2       2020-01-15 13:05:40
```

```
# This is what i need
f_num|call_id.x|t_num.x|retrieved_date.x   |call_id.y|f_num.y|retrieved_date.y
1     1         2       2020-01-12 12:03:34 2         2       2020-01-12 12:06:34
1     3         3       2020-01-15 13:02:40 4         2       2020-01-15 13:05:40
```

What can i do to filter the data to get the thing i want?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

A missed call is when a customer calls your number, is that right? If so I would do:

```
library(tidyverse)
called_back <- missed_call %>%
  inner_join(total_call, by = c("from_number" = "to_number"), 
             suffix = c("_from_missed_call" , "_from_total_call)

# Then create a variable with the time difference and filter accordingly
called_back %>%
   mutate(time_difference = as.numeric(difftime(retrieved_date_from_missed_call, retrieved_date_from_total_call) %>%
filter(time_difference <= 2)
```